# click function to specific slide (superslides plugin)

Tags: javascript

I have slider with 5 slides. And I have two links. The first link must go to slide 3 and second link must go to slide 5.
I cannot make this with standart pagination. I need click(function(), but I cannot find it in API of this plugin.

html:

```
<div id="slides">
 <ul class="slides-container">
    <li>
      slide 1
    </li>
    <li>
      slide 2
    </li>
    <li>
      slide 3
    </li>
    <li>
      slide 4
    </li>
    <li>
      slide 5
    </li>
 </ul>

 <header class="header">
   <a href="#" class="link">Link to slide 3</a>
   <a href="#" class="link1">Link to slide 5</a>
   <a href="#" class="link2">Link to google</a>
 </header>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#slides').superslides({
  animation: 'fade'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in href add hash width slide number

```
<a href="#3" class="link">Link to slide 3</a>
<a href="#5" class="link1">Link to slide 5</a>
```

**EDIT**

**html**

set attr **data-s** width *slide number* and class name **link**

```
<a href="javascript:" class="link" data-s="1">Link to slide 1</a>
<a href="javascript:" class="link" data-s="3">Link to slide 2</a>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.link').click(function(){
        var ind=parseInt($(this).data('s'));
        ind--;                
        $('#slides').superslides('animate' , ind)
      })
```

**EDIT 2**

**jquery**

```
$('.link').click(function(){
        var ind=parseInt($(this).data('s'));
        ind--;                
        $('#slides').superslides('animate' , ind)

        $('.link').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current')
      })
```

Comment: This is not an option, because pressed the link becomes active.

Comment: please check new solution

Comment: Also I need adding class "curren" to my link. For example I clicked "Link t slide2" and my code would become
<a href="javascript:" class="link current" data-s="3">Link to slide 2</a>

Comment: Works with problems EDIT 2. By clicking on link3 opens slide 2, when clicking on the link 1 - slider does not always work

Comment: Sorry for the long answer. The client refused the script. Therefore there is no need remake it.